# How do I change my keyboard layout back to English QWERTY on Kodachi Linux?

Tags: keyboard

For some reason the letter

```
I changes to a 5.
J changes to 1
K changes to 2
L changes to 3
M changes to 0
N is normal
O changes to 6
P changes to *
Q is normal
R is normal
S is normal
T is normal
U changes to 4
V is normal
W is normal
X is normal
Y is normal
Z is normal
```

I'm in the USA, American & use a US layout on my Dell Vostro 1520. What's the deal? How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you on a laptop with a reduced keyboard? Is the function key stuck down?

Comment: For reference, it appears to be [this type of laptop](https://www.notebookcheck.net/fileadmin/_migrated/pics/Dell_Vostro_1520_gesamt05_03.jpg). It may be that the `Fn` key or `FnLk` or `NumLk` or similar is in effect. I believe that the letters/numbers that he mentions are the blue variants printed on the keys.  It may be that the `Fn` key is stuck.

Comment: Yes, and this key is handled by the hardware, not the OS. So you will have to get it un-stuck.

Comment: Sounds just like NumLock being turned on, to me!

Comment: look closely at the keytops on your keyboard